# Spaces cannot be edited in comments

Tags: bug, whitespace, comment-edits

I cannot edit my comment to simply replace a space by a non-breakable space. The modification is not taken into account. The edit isn't performed. My comment is unchanged. Revision is lost. Stagnation prevails… Stasis. There is no future. That word will be forever hanging on the next line.

This is *terribly annoying*. Yes, it is.

Comment: I think it would benefit your question if you included that this is addressing french punctuation. Perhaps it would be a better fit on the local meta than for the entire exchange.

Comment: @Travis: French punctuation is a specific matter, and here is [the way to deal with that kind of animal](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/347/) (asked on the French meta). English requires non-breakable space between numbers and units or between initials and last name, just to name a few. Would you like your *J* cut from the *Travis*? Yes that sounds like a threat! But sure, I admit. I was bothered by hanging punctuation in this case.